# React-select sometimes doesn't display the options in the dropdown menu on async search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

strange one here. When using React-Select v1.0.0rc (although the bug occurs with all v1.x) using it in Async mode to search an API, **sometimes** the options will not show in the dropdown menu. There seems to be no reason for why this happens, but it happens with certain search queries and not others.

E.g `coconut` works but `coconut oil` doesnt, even though both return similar results.

The strange thing is that using the React chrome developer tools I can see that the options are set on the state of the Select, but they just don't appear. Also, if I click off the react-select, then click back on it, the results appear (tested in firefox and chrome). Here is my code and a few screenshots to illustrate

```
<Select.Async name={ this.generateName('ingredient_id')}
          loadOptions={this.getIngredients}
          className="admin-meal-ingredient-search-select"
          autoload={false}
          cache={false}
          multi={false}
          value={this.props.ingredient}
          onChange={this.props.handleIngredientChange}
          placeholder="Search for ingredient" />
```

#### Here you can see I have typed something in but no results are coming up

[image: Search term not showing images]

#### Here you can see the results in the React inspector in the options array

[image]

#### When I click away then click back on the box, the options are

appearing

[image: Click away and come back, there they are]

Comment: I am using just Select component same issue with onInputChange. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `"react-select": "^3.0.4",` and had to add `filterOption={false}` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's **filterOption**={false}, be careful with typing so you don't wonder why it's not working for you :)

Comment: Please read [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution and that is to set `filterOptions= {false}`

Comment: Sorry - but this answer just wasted me 1.5h. Its singular! (as mentioned below!) `filterOption={false}` :facepalm: